# Measuring the download speed of a webpage with Python requests

Tags: python, performance, python-requests

I need to measure the download speed of a webpage (html document) using requests.

I am trying this simple and easy approach:

```
def get_speed(response):
    download_speed = len(response.content) / response.elapsed.microseconds
    return download_speed * 976.5625  # converting to kb/s

session = requests.Session()
url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
speed = get_speed(response)
print(f"The page was downloaded with a speed of {speed}kb/s")
```

But the results are somewhat inconsistent: the measures I am getting are always very low, like 100/200kb/s maximum, while I am pretty much sure the speed of the connection I am using is way faster.

What's wrong with my approach? How can I improve it? Please note I do not need this for big/huge files but only for webpages, so using a stream-based approach could not be ideal for me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, it is just that the data you are downloading is so small and is done so quickly computing its speed is pretty much meaningless. For comparison run `wget stackoverflow.com` and see the different results.

Answer (score 1):

#### You need a big enough file for your result to be meaningful

Otherwise the overhead of making the call is the dominant factor.

Try this URL:

```
import requests

def get_speed(response):
    download_speed = len(response.content) / response.elapsed.microseconds
    return download_speed * 976.5625  # converting to kb/s

session = requests.Session()
url = "https://github.com/Apress/repo-with-large-file-storage/blob/master/LargeFile.zip?raw=true"
response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
speed = get_speed(response)

print(f"The page was downloaded with a speed of {speed}kb/s")
```

Comment: The problem is I must measure the speed of webpages, are there any other ways I could obtain a meaningful measure without increasing the size of the object I am downloading?

Comment: @Kodeeo You could measure "minimum" overhead and subtract it from `response.elapsed.microseconds`. This would be still far from perfect, but might give you **a bit** better results.